# Server refused our key - Creating instance from Snapshot

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-ec2

I lost my private key on a server because my hard drive was fried and I didn't have the folder with the key in it backed up. Consequently after research I found that I can make a snapshot of the EC2 instance and launch a new instance with a different key using the snapshot. I was able to do so and setup the new instance with a new key/pair. However, now I still cannot log on to the server through the Amazon client or with Putty SSH. Is there a there a time-frame I have to wait before the instance is SSH ready (i.e. 1 - 2 hours) or did I set it up wrong?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Did you use your snapshot as a root volume? or Did you add it to the instance as an additional volume?

Comment: Why the down-vote?? The title has the error message, "Server refused our key". I did convert the private key as putty can't even see the .pem file and I tried using the Amazon JAVA client with the private key as well, but both failed with that error message (AWS client said Authentication failed).

Comment: The snapshot is the only volume attached. In addition, how would that impact me from being able to SSH?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you ssh using windows m/c, then .ppk key is used and from unix systems .pem key is used. 
You can try it once more from an ami, create an ami from the instance and if any ebs volume is attached, consider that too. Use that ami to launch and instance and provide the key at the end as it asks for, if your using the aws web console. In your case create a new keypair to be used and then assign it.

Wait is generally 2-5 minutes for the instance to be up and then try to ssh. Right click on the newly launched instance and check for the log file output. In some cases it can give you the hint.

It is generally preferred to use ebs backed volumes to avoid situations like data loss.